# Kali Linux 32-bit installation stalls on a black screen in virtualbox 5.1.2 on Windows 10 64-bit

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, system-installation

I'am trying to install Kali Linux iso 32-bit on my Windows 10 64-bit on virtualbox. I tried PAE config in VB. VB is able to boot iso it reaches until installation menu but after clicking install it gets stuck on a black screen.

Comment: Any reason why you need Kali 32-bit instead of 64-bit?

Comment: No, there is no reason to do that, I have 32 bit iso hence I said that.

Comment: I'd go with a 64-bit ISO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enabled PC virtualisation in bios, disabled hyper-v in windows and installed virtualbox extension pack.